# TableLayout under LinearLayout is not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout

I used LinearLayout under that TextView and TableLayout.

Output:

I'm able see TextView contents in model but not TableLayout.

Please tell me what the mistake i did?

```
    LinearLayout quizlinear = new LinearLayout(this);
            quizlinear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            quizlinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            quizlinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            quiztextview = new TextView(this);
            quiztextview.setText("BEER THERE");
            quiztextview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            quiztextview.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
            quiztextview.setTextColor(Utils.getColor("#FFFFFF"));
            quiztextview.setTextSize(30);
            quizlinear.addView(quiztextview);

            quiztablelayout = new TableLayout(this);

            TableRow quiztablerow = new TableRow(this);
            quiztablerow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TableRow quiztablerow1 = new TableRow(this);
            quiztablerow1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ImageView arrowImg1 = new ImageView(this);
        arrowImg1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        arrowImg1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        quiztablerow.addView(arrowImg1);
                    ImageView arrowImg2 = new ImageView(this);
        arrowImg2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        arrowImg2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        quiztablerow.addView(arrowImg2);
             ImageView arrowImg3 = new ImageView(this);
        arrowImg3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        arrowImg3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    quiztablerow1.addView(arrowImg3);
                        ImageView arrowImg4 = new ImageView(this);
        arrowImg4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        arrowImg4.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    quiztablerow1.addView(arrowImg4);
quiztablelayout.addView(quiztablerow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        quiztablelayout.addView(quiztablerow1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         quizlinear.addView(quiztablelayout);
TextView quiztextview1 = new TextView(this);
            quiztextview1.setText("DONE THAT!");
            quiztextview1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            quiztextview1.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
            quiztextview1.setTextColor(Utils.getColor("#FFFFFF"));
            quiztextview1.setTextSize(30);
            quizlinear.addView(quiztextview1);

            TextView quiztextview2 = new TextView(this);
            quiztextview2.setText("Version1.0 copyrights @2011 janardhan solutions pvt ltd");
            quiztextview2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            quiztextview2.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            quiztextview2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            quiztextview2.setTextColor(Utils.getColor("#FFFFFF"));
            quiztextview2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            quiztextview2.setTextSize(10);
            quizlinear.addView(quiztextview2);


            setContentView(quizlinear);
```

Comment: Why are you not using xml files make views..????

Comment: Use a tutorial, people are not here to do your work!

Comment: Try to make a question correctly and concrete

Comment: add this  TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    table.setLayoutParams(lp); 
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

Answer (score 0):

change your  LayoutParams should be of android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams except one that supplied to **quiztablelayout**.addView(...)

```
quiztablelayout.addView(quiztablerow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
quiztablelayout.addView(quiztablerow1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        quizlinear.addView(quiztablelayout);
```